# NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG

Tags: angular, charts, angular-chart

I am working on the angular application, When I open my project it is giving me the error like below

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(IndexModule)[InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG -> InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken NGX_ECHARTS_CONFIG!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:71789:21)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84254:29)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84254:29)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84254:29)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:100306:31)
    at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84254:29)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:100306:31)
    at Object.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:97671:29)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:75308:31)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:87509:10)
```

tried with installation of [ngx-echarts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts)

```
npm install echarts -S
npm install ngx-echarts -S
```

Still getting the same above error

Answer (score 22, accepted):

import `NgxEchartsModule` in your app module (or any other proper angular module):

**With Dynamic import**

```
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      echarts: () => import('echarts')
    })
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**OR**

You can also directly pass the echarts instead which will slow down initial rendering because it will load the whole echarts into your main bundle.

```
import { NgxEchartsModule } from 'ngx-echarts';

import * as echarts from 'echarts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxEchartsModule.forRoot({
      echarts,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```